# Problems with pipeline GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am trying with a machine learning clasification problem.

The target is a multiclass, with 3 diferents class.

I have some problems with this pipeline, and I can not see what the problem is.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

scaler = StandardScaler()

pipe_gb = Pipeline(steps=[("scaler",scaler), ("gb", GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42))])

params_gb = [
    {'clasificador__learning_rate': np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.02), 'clasificador__n_estimators': np.arange(50,100, 2),
     "clasificador__max_depth": [1, 2, 3, 5], 'clasificador__loss': ['log_loss', 'exponential'], 
     'clasificador__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']}
]

gb = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe_gb, 
                  param_distributions = params_gb, 
                  scoring='accuracy', 
                  refit=True,
                  cv=5,
                  n_jobs=-1)

gb = gb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter clasificador for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                ('gb', GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is on `params_gb`;  please edit code like this:

```
    params_gb = 
{'gb__learning_rate': np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.02), 'gb__n_estimators': np.arange(50,100, 2),
 "gb__max_depth": [1, 2, 3, 5], 'gb__loss': ['log_loss', 'exponential'], 
 'gb__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']}
```

as per the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html).